# Fitting multiple PDF A4 pages to one A1 page

Tags: pdf, imposition

I need to convert this  [document](http://www.gjp.si/images/Dokumenti/Razno/GJP_Koledar_2013_2014_publikacija.pdf) , which has twelve A4 pages,
to something like [this](http://www.makspecar.si/olski%20hini%20red/Koledar%202013-14.pdf), to one A1 page (width:84,1 cm and height:59,4). I've searched a little over the internet about it, but I didn't find anything that could really help me.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO! Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Almost the same question as http://superuser.com/questions/366490/how-to-merge-multiple-pdf-files-onto-one-page-with-pdftk

Answer (score 2):

A far as I understand, you have a multipages A4 sized pdf and you need to **Impose** ***conveniently***  these A4 pages over an A1 sized page in order to fitting and cover the whole A1 area of A1 sheet with a4 pages

since an A1 **portrait oriented** ISO page has dimensions **59.4 x 84.1 cm**

and an A4 **portrait oriented** ISO page has dimensions **21 x 29.7 cm**

it follows that into an A1 **landscape** ISO page **84.1 x 59.4 cm** we can put (disposed into two rows) **4** A4 **portrait** pages for row

[image: gridfront]
[image: grid back]

in our case, having 12  A4 pages,. last 4 columns are left blank

this is called **imposition** and an easy, cross-platform  way to perform this task is using the excellent

you can use, on this last file,

**Multivalent.jar** (last free version with pdf tools included)

- https://rg.to/file/c6bd7f31bf8885bcaa69b50ffab7e355

with this syntax:

```
java -cp /path/to.../Multivalent.jar tool.pdf.Impose -dim 4x2 -paper 84.1x59.4cm file.pdf
```

and the result will be this:

- your 12  A4 pages pdf imposed into an A1 page
- http://ge.tt/9GLLkNt/v/0

[image: calendar_imposed_front-little.png]

[image: calendar_imposed_back-little.png]

but if you want all 12 months (pages) into **one A1 page** you can:

place these 12 pages on a 6x2 grid that fits in A1 landscape bigger dimension (**84.1**); so, you need to divide this dimension by six (to simplify you'll divide **84 cm by 6** omitting the decimal

you'll have a width of **14 cm**

now, since if you resize the page to fit, the dimensions  must to have the same original ratio of original A4 page, you'll calculate this ratio dividing **29.7/21** = **1.41428571428571**

now you multiply **14** for **1.41428571428571** and you'll have another dimension (the **height**) = **19.8 cm** having the same **geometry** of A4 original page, since you have **proportionally scaled** with this syntax:

```
java -cp /path/to.../Multivalent.jar tool.pdf.Impose -dim 1x1  -paper 14x19.8cm GJP_Koledar_2013_2014_publikacija.pdf
```

and rename the resulting pdf file **14x19.8.pdf**

[image: 21x29.7]
[image: 14x19.8]

now, on resulting **resized multipage pdf** you'll perform this **IMPOSITION**

```
java -cp /path/to../Multivalent.jar tool.pdf.Impose -dim 6x2  -paper 84.1x39.6 cm 14x19.8.pdf
```

with these results:

[image]

then, as **final stage** you'll center this grid of *6 columns x 2rows* measuring **84.1x39.6 cm** in an A1 landscape ISO page

with the help of **jpdftweak**

- http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net/

using these settings: (**center instead of enlarge** in page size tab)

[image: jpdftweak]

final results:
[image: inA1]